# PC wakes from hibernate by keyboard and mouse

Tags: keyboard, mouse, hibernate, acpi

My new PC wakes from hibernate by pressing any key on keyboard (PS/2) or mouse (USB); just like sleep mode (with the difference that power LED doesn't blink).

If I uncheck "Allow this device to wake the computer" for them, PC doesn't wake from hibernate by keyboard and mouse anymore but it also affects sleep mode.

I checked BIOS settings; "Power On By PS/2 Keyboard" is "Disabled". So why it wakes by keyboard and mouse? I don't like this behavior. I want it to be as other normal systems: wake from sleep by mouse and keyboard, wake from hibernate only by power button.

Resetting BIOS settings didn't solve the problem.

Motherboard: Asus A320M-K
BIOS: AMI 5603
OS: Windows 10 Pro 20H2 (installed from official ISO file - still no update)
CPU: AMD Ryzen 3 3200G

Comment: Please ellaborate on what do you want to achieve? Do you want your keyboard and mouse not to power on the pc?

Comment: @binaryOps20 Sorry I forgot to mention it. See edited post.

Comment: I believe the problem is caused by [`hybrid sleep`](https://www.howtogeek.com/102897/whats-the-difference-between-sleep-and-hibernate-in-windows/). Your PC is hibernated -> actual state is saved on disk, but also is kept in RAM (it is still powered). It means PC is in standard sleep - it could to recover really fast, but when it lost a power during the sleep it is able to recover its state from a disk. You can disable hybrid sleep, then hibernation means save state to a disk and power off the PC.

Comment: @binaryOps20 I disabled hybrid sleep. No change.

Comment: I booted from Peppermint OS 10 USB and then hibernated. Same thing happened. This behavior also happens if I shut down PC when fast startup is enabled. I think the problem happens when computer enters S4 power state. Maybe this is a BIOS firmware bug.

Comment: @AmirSinaMashayekh Try to disable USB devices power during S4 state. See [Asus Guide](https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1042220/)

Comment: @Lluser "USB power delivery in Soft Off State (S5)" is already disabled; also my keyboard is PS/2.